# Redisplaying data from my server / missing a step

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

When I save "Ben and Jerry's" to my database, and later recall it from the database, into an input tag (so I can edit/resave it), I get

```
Ben & Jerry&#39;s
```

*Where am I going wrong?* (Notice that the "&" is correctly translated, but the apostraphe is not). Let me summarise what I am doing...

My web pages have

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

and my server dispenses JSON data via PHP and

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

My web form, using javascript/jquery, pre-post, pushes all form data thru

```
encodeURIComponent()
```

My PHP server code reads the data and pre-db-insert uses

```
filter_var() and FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
```

My mysql db created with "utf8 - default collation" and my insert writes

```
Ben & Jerry&#39;s
```

Later.... I do a mysql select, and I thought I need only javascript call

```
decodeURIComponent()
```

to convert everything back to "Ben & Jerry's" but this appears not to be the case.

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't need to be encoding or decoding that unless you're using it in the URL. As long as you are sanitizing the string before it goes into your database you can just store the string `Ben & Jerry's` without worrying about the apostrophe.

Comment: The value has been HTML encoded. There's nothing specifically wrong with this, you just need to find out where that's happening in your code and remove it if it's not required.

Comment: you need to figure out WHERE the uri encoding is occuring. if it's in the database like that, look at the insert code. if it comes OUT of the database with a `'`, then look at the output code.

Comment: I convert my input to reduce/avoid injection - so perhaps my method is wrong. Should I use PHP html_entity_decode() after reading from the database? Am I createing more work than I need to?

Comment: Are you only converting quotes to prevent SQL injections? If so use parameterized queries. If you are encoding special chars to prevent XSS injections that `&` should also have been encoded. Maybe add your code for `inserting` and `selecting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, and the two links below, I went with prepared statements. I had avoided such until now because of inexperience - I write old school procedure code and most examples given on the php.net page have moved from that style. I hope something here and above helps others...

[What is parameterized Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query)

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Thanks everyone

Comment: `pdo` and `mysqli` are both options that support parameterized queries. The `mysqli` has the procedural style still.